# Freeing a singly linked list in c

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

I've come across what seems to be a strange problem when implementing a singly linked list. I call a list_destroyer and pass the pointer to the head of the list, however when the method returns, the pointer that is passed still points to a full list. I don't believe I've passed a struct anywhere.

Here is my struct list, and typedef

```
typedef struct list list_t
struct list{
    void* datum;
    list_t* next;
};
```

And here is the code that is causing problem

```
void list_destroy(list_t *head){
    list_t *destroy = head;
    while(head){
        //printf("%d \n", list_size(head));
        head = head->next;
        free(destroy);
        destroy = head;
    }
    //printf("%d \n", list_size(head));
    head = NULL;
    //printf("%d \n", list_size(head));
}
```

The list_size functions have been commented out because they aren't necessary, but I use them to see the output of the code. The printf output shows that the size is decreasing. The two printf's surrounding the "head = NULL;" statement both print a size of zero. This is also confirmed with gdb. However, when I have this code (following) calling list_destroy, the pointer that is passed through is unchanged.

```
int main(){
    list_t *test = NULL;
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    list_append(test,&a);
    list_append(test,&b);
    printf("%d \n", list_size(test));
    list_destroy(test);
    printf("%d \n", list_size(test));
}
```

I still get the printf above and below the list_destroy to both output 2. I haven't initialized a new list_t anywhere, so I don't see how the printf after the list_destroy would still output 2, (especially when the printf within the list_destroy says the list_t* passed in has a size of 0 at the end.

Comment: I don't know if this is an adequate explanation (I haven't looked at your code in detail) but freeing memory doesn't overwrite it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> however when the method returns, the pointer that is passed still points to a full list.

That's incorrect: when the function returns, the pointer points to what used to be a full list. Chances are, your system would let you traverse the entire list without a break. However, dereferencing this pointer after the call is *undefined behavior*, so the same code could crash on other systems.

The problem has a name - `head` becomes a *dangling pointer*.

Fixing the problem is easy - pass a pointer to pointer, and set it to `NULL` upon completion:

```
void list_destroy(list_t **headPtr){
    list_t *head = *headPtr;
    list_t *destroy = head;
    while(head){
        head = head->next;
        free(destroy);
        destroy = head;
    }
    *headPtr = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Is this really different to what I have? Your usage of *headPtr is equivalent to my list_t *head, isn't it? and I have a line "head = NULL;" at the very end. So the pointer shouldn't be dangling. Is my thought process wrong here?

Comment: @DrewKay The assignment `head = NULL` in your code has no effect on the pointer passed into `list_destroy`, because pointers are passed by value. `list_destroy` gets its own private copy of `test` from `main`. It is allowed to assign it whatever it wishes; `test` in the `main` function would remain the same. My modification passes the pointer by pointer, letting the assignment inside `list_destroy` modify `test` pointer from your `main` function.

Comment: Ahh, thanks. That makes sense. However, this is for a class project and the implementation calls for list_destroy(list_t *head), so I'll email the professor and see if there is a mistake.

Comment: @DrewKay Although passing a pointer to pointer into `list_destroy` is not uncommon, another solution is to pass a pointer, and manually assign `NULL` to `test` after the function returns. This is error-prone, but programmers do it anyway.

Comment: Thanks. It didn't solve my problem, but you did show me why I have a problem, so I've marked you as the answer.